# Update of a datatable after progressbar completes

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to fire a JavaScipt function after progress bar completes. I tried to nest the following tag:

```
<p:ajax event="complete" oncomplete="refreshTable();"/>
```

I also tried to add a progress bar component via a backing bean like in the code below:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
progressBar.setAjax(true);
AjaxBehavior ajaxAction = new AjaxBehavior();
ajaxAction.setOncomplete("refreshTable();");
progressBar.addClientBehavior("complete", ajaxAction);
```

But ultimately no JS function get's called.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Technologies used: *PrimeFaces 3.5, Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206), PrimeFaces Extensions 0.6.3, GlassFish 3.1.2.2*.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the update attribute. If your dataTable id is id="myDataTable" then you should use:

```
<p:progressBar ajax="true" value="#{progressBean.progress}">  
    <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{...}" update="myDataTable"/>  
</p:progressBar>
```

Comment: How do you do that programmatically?

Comment: You should debug and check if the List is being populated

Answer (score 0):

As PrimeFaces showcase clearly states, you should use the [`<p:progressBar>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/progressBar.jsf) with `<p:ajax>` tag nested within it. You specify *component ids to be rerendered in `update` attribute* and *client-side callback in `oncomplete` attribute* of `<p:ajax>`, by replacing the ellipsis in a code like:

```
<p:progressBar ajax="true" value="#{bean.progressVar}">
    <p:ajax event="complete" update="..." oncomplete="..."/>  
</p:progressBar>
```

Note that you might prefer to rerender the datatable by JSF by specifying `update` attribute instead of doing some job manually on the client by specifying `oncomplete` attribute. The latter is typically used to trigger some client-side GUI changes like showing/hiding components, switching style classes, opening dialogs, etc. but not to perform actions that belong to the server-side functioning.

---

Regarding the programmatic addition of ajax behaviour to components, your `<p:ajax event="complete" update="table-id" oncomplete="refreshTable()"/>` should programmatically be equivalent to:

```
AjaxBehavior ab = new AjaxBehavior();
ab.setUpdate("table-id");
ab.setOncomplete("refreshTable()");
component.addClientBehavior("complete", ab);
```

Comment: progressbar is created at runtime so... how do I programmatically do that in my backing bean where the progressabar is created

Comment: If something doesn't work post console messages and trace to the point that's not working.

Comment: There are no errors but the table is not updating , what do you suggest?